# Why is my code parsing a sorted JSON file into unsorted list? | Haskell and Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse a nested JSON file which looks like this

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "MSFT",
        "2: Indicator": "Relative Strength Index (RSI)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2018-10-17 10:31:05",
        "4: Interval": "weekly",
        "5: Time Period": 10,
        "6: Series Type": "open",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern Time"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: RSI": {
        "2018-10-17 10:31:05": {
            "RSI": "54.5653"
        },
        "2018-10-12": {
            "RSI": "63.0279"
        },
        "2018-10-05": {
            "RSI": "74.7519"
        },
        "2018-09-28": {
            "RSI": "72.1573"
        },
        "2018-09-21": {
            "RSI": "74.8123"
        },
        "2018-09-14": {
            "RSI": "66.7116"
        },
        "2018-09-07": {
            "RSI": "75.8051"
          ...
          ...
          ... and so on
```

---

My goal is to get the latest/uppermost "RSI" value. Since the key (the dates) are variable, I'm trying to get it without matching the keys.

---

This is what I've got so far

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

module Tesst where

import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import           Data.HashMap.Strict  as S
import           Data.Text
import           Data.Time
import           GHC.Exts
import           GHC.Generics
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)

newtype TechnicalAnalysis = TechnicalAnalysis {
                   rsiQuote  :: Object
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)


instance FromJSON TechnicalAnalysis where
  parseJSON = withObject "RSI Quote" $
    \o -> do
      rsiQuote <- o        .: "Technical Analysis: RSI"
      return TechnicalAnalysis {..}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Which ticker? "
  symbolToQuote <- getLine
  d <- (eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp ("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=RSI&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=FI2KMDSAE&symbol=" ++ symbolToQuote)) :: IO (Either String TechnicalAnalysis)
  case d of
    Left e   -> print e
    Right qt -> print $ Prelude.map (\(a, b) -> (read (unpack a) :: Day, b)) (S.toList (rsiQuote qt))
```

---

What I get running the code is this:

```
[(2005-09-02,Object (fromList [("RSI",String "60.8860")])),(2017-12-29,Object (fromList [("RSI",String "71.1921")])),(2011-09-16,Object (fromList [("RSI",String "50.3489")])),(2000-05-12,Object (fromList [("RSI",String "33.6402")]))...
```

as you can see, all the values are out of order.

---

My questions are:

1. Why isn't it just printing out that JSON file as it is?
2. Is it possible to get the latest RSI value without sorting the
   result?

Comment: JSON objects are inherently unordered, so the same file can result in all possible key-value pair orders.

Comment: As for your second question, calculating the *maximum* can be done in *linear time*.

Comment: You have to distinguish between two things: the abstract *object* that the JSON represents, and the concrete *serialization* that is actually stored in the file. The serialization has to choose *some* ordering of the keys (since files themselves are ordered sequences of bytes), but whatever order is chosen is unrelated to the the object itself. The only way to represent order in JSON is to use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen the essentially dynamically-typed `Object` as your semantic object. Choose something better; `Map Day Double`, e.g., or `ArgMax Day Double` if you *really* only want the latest RSI value and will never look at anything else.

For example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.HashMap.Strict as S
import Data.List.NonEmpty
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Text
import Data.Time

-- can't use readMaybe, 2018-10-17 10:31:05 has extra non-Day gunk at the end
jsonReadText :: Read a => String -> Text -> Parser a
jsonReadText err t = case reads (unpack t) of
    (v,_):_ -> return v
    _ -> fail $ "could not parse " ++ unpack t ++ " as " ++ err

newtype RSI = RSI Double deriving Show

instance FromJSON RSI where
    parseJSON = withObject "object with RSI key" $ \o -> do
        t <- o .: pack "RSI"
        RSI <$> jsonReadText "Double" t

newtype LatestRSI = LatestRSI (ArgMax Day RSI) deriving Show

instance FromJSON LatestRSI where
    parseJSON = withObject "RSI Quote" $ \o -> do
        quoteMap <- o .: pack "Technical Analysis: RSI"
        quotes <- forM (S.toList quoteMap) $ \(dayText, rsiValue) -> do
            day <- jsonReadText "Day" dayText
            rsi <- parseJSON rsiValue
            return (Max (Arg day rsi))
        case quotes of
            [] -> fail "expected non-empty collection of RSI quotes"
            q:qs -> return . LatestRSI . sconcat $ q :| qs
```

Example usage in ghci:

```
> bs <- Data.ByteString.Lazy.readFile "test.json"
> eitherDecode bs :: Either String LatestRSI
Right (LatestRSI (Max {getMax = Arg 2018-10-17 (RSI 54.5653)}))
```

Comment: That's far better than my implementation! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also if you wouldn't mind, could you add a bit more documentation to your code? I'm still very new to haskell so it'll be a massive help following your thought processes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with Willem's directions (in the comments).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

module Tesst where

import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import           Data.HashMap.Strict  as S
import           Data.List
import           Data.Text
import           Data.Time
import           GHC.Exts
import           GHC.Generics
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)


newtype TechnicalAnalysis = TechnicalAnalysis {
                   rsiQuote  :: Object
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)


instance FromJSON TechnicalAnalysis where
  parseJSON = withObject "RSI Quote" $
    \o -> do
      rsiQuote <- o        .: "Technical Analysis: RSI"
      return TechnicalAnalysis {..}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Which ticker? "
  symbolToQuote <- getLine
  d <- (eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp ("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=RSI&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=FI2KMC2DSAE&symbol=" ++ symbolToQuote)) :: IO (Either String TechnicalAnalysis)
  case d of
    Left e   -> print e
    Right qt -> do
      let l = S.toList (rsiQuote qt)
      print $ maximumBy (\(a, _) (b, _) -> compare a b) l
```

---

This was the key

```
maximumBy (\(a, _) (b, _) -> compare a b)
```